# Generating Terraform resources within a loop fails if reference doesn't exist yet

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We have an API Gateway which has a lot of option endpoints. I wanted to simplify the terraform code and I came up with the following:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "comms_options_methods" {
  for_each    = toset([
    aws_api_gateway_resource.api-drafts-id.id,
    ...
  ])
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id = each.key
  http_method = "OPTIONS"
  authorization = "NONE"
}
```

The code above runs if the resources in `toset` are defined. If they aren't then I get back the following error:

> The "for_each" set includes values derived from resource attributes
> that cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot
> determine the full set of keys that will identify the instances of
> this resource.
>
> When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to use a map
> value where the keys are defined statically in your configuration and
> where only the values contain apply-time results.

I thought that meant doing something like this:

```
locals {
  api_options_resources = [
    "api-drafts-id",
    ...
  ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "comms_options_methods" {
  for_each    = { for name in local.api_options_resources : name => aws_api_gateway_resource[name].id }
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id = each.key
  http_method = "OPTIONS"
  authorization = "NONE"
}
```

This leads to the message 'Invalid reference to the above on api_gateway_options.tf line 29, in resource "aws_api_gateway_method"'. Line 29 is the for_each loop.

All the resource names are valid. Am I approaching this from completely the wrong angle here? Is there a way to get something like this working?

Thanks.

Comment: There might be a way to do it differently. Can you add the `aws_api_gateway_resource` to the question?